# Android Nexus7 2012/2013でレイアウトファイル(.xml)を分けたい

Tags: android, android-layout

Android StudioでAndroidアプリの開発を行っております。

現在はlayoutフォルダを`layout-sw600dp`としており、Nexus7(2012)とNexus7(2013)で共通のレイアウトファイル(.xml)を使用しております。
しかし、それぞれ別のレイアウトファイルを使用するように修正したいのですが実現できません。

`layout-sw600dp-tvdpi`、`layout-sw600dp-mdpi`とlayoutフォルダを作成してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

実現方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus7(2012) は`tvdpi`、Nexus7(2013) は`xhdpi`なので
`layout-sw600dp-tvdpi`と`layout-sw600dp-xhdpi`に分けると上手く行くはずです。

Comment: 上記の通り

layout-sw600dp-tvdpiにNexus7(2012) 用の、
layout-sw600dp-xhdpiにNexus7(2013) 用の
レイアウトファイルを振り分ける事により、期待した動きになりました！

ご回答いただきまして誠にありがとうございました。